# UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using **MFSideMenu** controller for most of the apps which have side menu function. All the apps are working fine on iOS 7 and prior versions but NOT on iPhone 6 devices running iOS 8 (Works fine on iPhone 5 running iOS8).
I cannot seem to figure out what to do to resolve this error that I am receiving. When click on a cell on the LeftMenu UITableView, app crashes and gives this error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fc492877e00 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fc492634860>
```

Note: UITableView is a XIB IBOutlet

This is how the code looks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    // This will remove extra space on top of the tableview
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    // This will remove extra separators from tableview
    self.tblViewMenu.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // menu titles
    arrMenu = [Config returnArrLeftMenu];

    // check login status
    [self checkLoginStatus];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";

MenuCell *mCell = (MenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];

// menu cell
if (mCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[MenuCell class]])
        mCell = (MenuCell *)oneObject;

}

    mCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    mCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mCell.lblTitle.text = [arrMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return mCell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // load selected menu view on to the MAinViewController
    MainViewController *mainController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

    mainController.title = [arrMenu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mainController.menuIndex = (int)indexPath.row;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;
    NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainController];
    navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
    [self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];

}
```

Comment: You do know what the error message means, right?

Comment: well do you use any kvo:s for your tableview?

Comment: Yes, app crashes due to deallocation of the UITableView. But I cannot figure out why. Because, I am using ARC as well as TableView is an IBOutlet. Exception occurs only on iPhone 6 devices running iOS 8

Comment: @Eyeball I didn't get it. What is kvo:s?

Comment: @Eyeball I had a look what kvo:s means :) I am not using kvo:s for tableview. Also I went through the MFSideMenu classes, seems its not using kvo:s

Comment: try posting some more code from your VC. also, paste your cell, if you are using custom cells

Comment: one thing to note, which probably is not the error here, is that your CustomCellIdentifier has a trailing whitespace

Comment: Yes. It had accidentally, I removed the whitespace, now its working :) thanks a lot for the guidance. Can you share with me the reason for that? I din't face such an exception before

Comment: You can try strong attribute in @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Answer (score 12):

You are likely observing a property change of the TableView with code like this:

```
[self.tblViewMenu addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil]
```

The reference to the observer (your class instance) is stored with a unsafe unretained semantic. You will have to clean that up during dealloc() to avoid app crashes (ARC can't handle this for you).

So your dealloc() should deregister the observer like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self.tblViewMenu removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}
```

You'll have to replace "frame" with the name of the property that your are interested in.

Be sure to check the basic concepts of Key-Value-Observing (KVO) in the proper [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

**EDIT**

I just checked the source code of [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu). There is no sign of KVO-usage in that code, so the crash is likely not caused by that component.

Answer (score 5):

For the swift version you can use the "deinit" method to remove all observers

```
 deinit {
    self.yourtable.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "keyname")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your tableView is actually getting cleaned up correctly before your controller is deallocated? Try adding a `-(void) dealloc{}`  method to your controller and put a breakpoint in it. If your controller still has a reference to tableView when dealloc gets called it will cause exactly the sort of issue you are seeing.

If that is the case then you will need to override the [removeFromParentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/removeFromParentViewController)

method of the controller and manually set the tableView property to nil. For example:

```
-(void) removeFromParentViewController {
    [super removeFromParentViewController];
    if(self.tableView!=nil) {
        self.tableView.delegate = nil;
        self.tableView.dataSource = nil;
        self.tableView = nil;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!